# Custom Storyboard Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a custom storyboard segue animation but its not coming out the way I want it to. Instead of "wiping" in over the view controller, I want it to "push" away the current view controller with the new one next to it. (not like the push segue, more like the the effect seen in the photos app when you swipe through photos). Any ideas? Thanks.

```
- (void)perform {

UIViewController *currentViewController = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *newViewController = self.destinationViewController;


[currentViewController.view addSubview:newViewController.view];


newViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05);


CGPoint originalCenter = newViewController.view.center;

newViewController.view.center = self.originatingPoint;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.9
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     newViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 100.0);
                     newViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [newViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                     [currentViewController presentViewController:newViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
                 }];
}
```

[image]

Comment: so what is not working with the code you posted?

Comment: I'd recommend just using [currentViewController presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

When doing a custom animation using UIViewAnimationOptionCurve it only does a page swiping animation, and not a swipe from left to right.

Comment: @meda This slides in the new view controller on top of the current view controller, I want to to have it push the new view controller in and the current one out.

Comment: @user3186310 do you want it to still show the past view controller?

Comment: @meda i added a photo to the question on what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @meda I want to have the current view be pushed out by the new view controller. The photo is how would it would look "mid push". (again, not like the standard push segue) Thanks.

Comment: @DestinyDawn I tried it, and it still doesn't achieve the effect I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @user3186310 are your viewController embeded in a navigationcontroller?

Comment: no, but again I'm not trying to do the standard push segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
animations:^{
    newViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 100.0);
    newViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
}
```

It looks like you're not animating the current view controller's view. I'm also not sure why you're setting the transform of your new view controller's view. I'd expect your code to look something like this:

```
CGPoint originalCenter = currentViewController.view.center;
CGPoint newCurrentVCCenter = CGPointMake(currentViewController.view.center.x - screenWidth, currentViewController.center.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.9
                  delay:0.0
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
animations:^{
    currentViewController.center = newCurrentVCCenter;
    newViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){
     // clean up here
}];
```

In other words, you're moving `currentViewController.view` and `newViewController.view`, so that the current view and new view both shift left the same amount and at the same time.

Comment: where do i put the animation block?

Comment: Same place you have it currently. I just took a snippet of your code. Note that you'll probably need to tweak it a bit -- you'll need to provide a definition for `screenWidth` for example. My main point is that you're hoping that both views will slide left together, but your animation block only moves one of the views.

Comment: So what about the second animation block? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is no second animation block -- I've only modified yours. I omitted the first part of that call because I was trying to be brief, but I can certainly see how it's confusing. Updated now.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the answer. Helped a ton!

Comment: Ok, I set everything up and it slides away the current view controller but doesn't slide in the new view controller. Any ideas?